# Find out timer resolution on old and new Linux systems

Tags: linux-kernel, posix

How can I find the resolution of system timers on Linux/POSIX systems? In particular I'm interested in the smallest time `nanosleep()` can wait. My existing implementation calls `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` which works fine on old kernels (<=2.4). It returns the number of clock ticks per second which in those days seemed to correspond to the resolution of timers (1/[jiffy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jiffy_(time))).

However, modern machines are generally using (a) [time stamp counters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter)/[high precision event timers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Precision_Event_Timer) and (b) ["tickless" kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tickless_kernel). They aren't using fixed timer-interrupt intervals anymore so `_SC_CLK_TCK` doesn't make sense anymore. On these machines `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` often returns 100 although the actual timer granularity is much smaller.

Is there a way I can detect (ideally from C/C++ code) if I'm running on a new system where `sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK)` doesn't correspond to timer granularity anymore? In this case I would like to return 0.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest time you can wait for with `nanosleep()` is driven by several factors:

1. [timer slack](https://lwn.net/Articles/588086/)
2. [context-switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) time
3. [timer accuracy and precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision)

With a default [timer slack value of 50 µs](https://manpath.be/f34/2/prctl#L1052), even when calling nanosleep with 0 ns or 1 ns duration you effectively wait for 50 µs or so, by default, if your process runs under normal (OTHER) scheduling.

You can disable the timer slack mechanism via a `prctl()` call or by running your process under a realtime scheduling class.

However, a nanosleep call then still yields a voluntary context switch, which takes 3 µs or so, depending on your hardware.

There isn't really a direct way to query the accuracy/precision of the timer used by nanosleep. POSIX specifies that nanosleep should measure against `CLOCK_REALTIME` and you can query its resolution with [`clock_getres()`](https://manpath.be/f34/2/clock_getres). However, the timer's accuracy/precision might be lower than that.

But you can simply indirectly query nanosleep's accuracy/precision by calling it for some small values with a few repetitions, at program start, e.g. 1 ns, 1 µs, 10 µs, and measure its real runtime against `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME)` or against the CPU's [TSC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter).

Answer (score 0):

My (greater) experience is on the BSD's, and their [nanosleep](https://manpage.me/?nanosleep) *is* POSIX.1 (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008). It appears related to `libc`. So (even on Linux) you could probably find some clues in `time.h`. You may well be able to find some pointers to the (high)precision timers you're looking for. I don't have a Linux box handy. So I'm unable to confirm. But HTH! :)